# JavaFX: Changing cursor during drag and drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, javafx-2, mouse-cursor

I'm trying to change the cursor on my Node during a drag and drop, but the image is not changing.  I'm calling `setCursor()` in the `DragDetectedEventHandler` of my node.  I've also tried calling `getParent().setCursor()` and had the same result.  I've also tried doing this in the other various event handler such as mouse down and drag over.  At best, I get the image to change after the mouse button is release, but I need the image to be different during the drag.  Anyone know how to do this?

```
private class DragDetectedEventHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        System.out.println("Drag Detected");
        Dragboard db = startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString("sample-drag-text");
        db.setContent(content);
        setCursor(_imageCursor);
        mouseEvent.consume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
((Node) mouseEvent.getSource()).setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
```

If doesn't work post your full code of class which includes your DragDetectedEventHandler.