# Dragging with invisible Dragboard in JavaFX 8

Tags: java, javafx

I borrowed code from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/HelloDragAndDrop.java.html).

Here is the code:

```
package hellodraganddrop;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Demonstrates a drag-and-drop feature.
 */
public class HelloDragAndDrop extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        stage.setTitle("Hello Drag And Drop");

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200);
        scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGREEN);

        final Text source = new Text(50, 100, "DRAG ME");
        source.setScaleX(2.0);
        source.setScaleY(2.0);

        final Text target = new Text(250, 100, "DROP HERE");
        target.setScaleX(2.0);
        target.setScaleY(2.0);

        source.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                /* drag was detected, start drag-and-drop gesture*/
                System.out.println("onDragDetected");

                /* allow any transfer mode */
                Dragboard db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

                /* put a string on dragboard */
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putString(source.getText());
                db.setContent(content);

                event.consume();
            }
        });

        target.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                /* data is dragged over the target */
                System.out.println("onDragOver");

                /* accept it only if it is  not dragged from the same node
                 * and if it has a string data */
                if (event.getGestureSource() != target &&
                        event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                    /* allow for both copying and moving, whatever user chooses */
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
                }

                event.consume();
            }
        });

        target.setOnDragEntered(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                /* the drag-and-drop gesture entered the target */
                System.out.println("onDragEntered");
                /* show to the user that it is an actual gesture target */
                if (event.getGestureSource() != target &&
                        event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                    target.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                }

                event.consume();
            }
        });

        target.setOnDragExited(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                /* mouse moved away, remove the graphical cues */
                target.setFill(Color.BLACK);

                event.consume();
            }
        });

        target.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                /* data dropped */
                System.out.println("onDragDropped");
                /* if there is a string data on dragboard, read it and use it */
                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                boolean success = false;
                if (db.hasString()) {
                    target.setText(db.getString());
                    success = true;
                }
                /* let the source know whether the string was successfully
                 * transferred and used */
                event.setDropCompleted(success);

                event.consume();
            }
        });

        source.setOnDragDone(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                /* the drag-and-drop gesture ended */
                System.out.println("onDragDone");
                /* if the data was successfully moved, clear it */
                if (event.getTransferMode() == TransferMode.MOVE) {
                    source.setText("");
                }

                event.consume();
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().add(source);
        root.getChildren().add(target);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

When drag detected it creates bended paper on the scene, and "DROP HERE" text catches it.

[image: example]

Is it possible to make it invisible or transparent? I tried any type of TransferMode but it is still existing.

The only solution came to my mind was just adding transparent png to DragBoard, but when drag detected on "DROP HERE" text some kind of plus icon is appearing below the cursor.

Are there any proper ways of implementing this feature?

Comment: If you want to get rid of the cursor, have a look on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40984625/4629012).

Comment: So, the solution just make as shown above and change the cursor?

Comment: I have no bended paper but I have the cursor. The cursor could be removed as shown in the answer I link.